# Passing characters and non-printable values into LLDB as arguments

Tags: debugging, gdb, lldb

With lldb, how can I pass in a long string - which includes hex characters - as a command line argument ?  Some of the hex characters may be non-printable.

```
(lldb) setting set target.run-args "AAAA\\x66\\x6f\\x6f"

(lldb) settings show target.run-args
target.run-args (array of strings) =
  [0]: "AAAA\x66\x6f\x6f"

// when I want it to read: "AAAAfoo"
```

In gdb I could use `echo -n -e 'AAAA\x66\x6f\x6f'`.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.  If the goal arguments sent into `lldb` are:

```
string 1:  "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFF" appended with 0x00000e30
string 2:  "GGGGYYYYZZZZ"
```

Using `printf` instead of `echo` the following worked:

```
B=$(printf "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFF\x30\x0e\x00\x00")
lldb my_c_program $B "GGGGYYYYZZZZ"
```

This is the interesting bit.

```
(lldb) settings show target.run-args
target.run-args (array of strings) =
  [0]: "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFF0"
  [1]: "GGGGYYYYZZZZ"
```

As you have unprintable characters, it is easy to think lldb didn't receive the characters.  That is not the case.  If you `lldb) run` even the non-printable characters are passed correctly.